# redis mass insertion consistency or limitation

Tags: redis

I need to insert 6925144 unique keys to redis, where each key contains hash of data.

I use the script in ruby that were published in [the main page](http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert).

The  whole insertion takes ~3 min `DBSIZE` after insertion is 1277553, but I expected it to be 6925144.

I am not sure that redis misses some records, may be calculation of `DBSIZE` is different for `HASH`, or may be 1277553 is just some natural limitation.

What is the best and the easiest way to check the consistence of the insertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure about the number of records there should be the diff in `DBSIZE` is most likely real.

- Keep an eye on the logs when doing the insert.
- Do you have duplicates in the dataset? Need of a merge-function?
- Does the ID get correctly encoded into a unique string or 32/64-bit int?